# How to fulton gun emplacements that are under the shed?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

The shed woth four pillars and a camo net houses a gun placed on a tripod that I could fulton if it weren't under the shed? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objects under any kind of cover cannot be extracted with the standard Fulton device.

Eventually the Wormhole Extraction Device is unlocked for development after completing Side Op 50 allowing for extraction from any location.

To develop the device after acquiring the schematic you will need:
850,000 GMP,
R&D Lvl. 40 and
Support Lvl. 40